# Are following statement about eigenvectors and eigenvalues correct?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If there are n distinct eigenvalues, then there are eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues are independent.

If there are same n eigenvalues, then eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues are not independent.

Are above statements true?

Comment: Yes and no. (The problem with the second statement is that it's not clear what "eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues" means when the eigenvalues are the same. You need to be more careful here; the correct statement involves the theory of Jordan normal form, or equivalently of generalized eigenspaces.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is correct. That is, the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

To address your second statement, we can discuss the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of a given eigenvalue. Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear transformation, the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is defined to be its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial of the transformation, while the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the dimension of the $\lambda$-eigenspace. Using the above definitions, the following fact addresses your second question.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $n$ and geometric multiplicity $d$. Then $1 \le d \le n$. That is, one can find at least one, but no more than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.